# Fixed positioned sidebar between top div and footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make fixed positioned side div which should start behaving fixed only when user scrolls reached at second section where it is actually present and should remain stay fixed till user scroll reached footer. Code should be responsive also. Fixed div should not visible in responsive(mobile layout).

```css
.fixed-div {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:pink;height:50px;color:white;" class="header">
  i am header
</div>
<div style="background:black;height:600px;color:white;" class="top">
  top section
</div>
<div style="display:flex;">
  <div style="width:40%;background:red;" class="fixed-div">
    i am left fixed div
  </div>
  <div style="width:60%;background:yellow;margin-left:auto;">
    <div style="height:70%;">i am right 1st div</div>
    <div style="height:70%;">i am right 2nd div</div>
    <div style="height:70%;">i am right 3rd div</div>
    <div style="height:70%;">i am right 4th div</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div style="background:black;height:500px;color:white;" class="header">
  i am footer
</div>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a site where people will write free code for you, you need to try first to write this, If you will face problems then you are most welcome to share them with us...